# Correct way of getting multiple records from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I always used the loop method to get all records from resource received from `mysql_query()`, but I wonder is there a easier way to accomplish this task?

e.g.:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables;
```

I suppose it should either way return more, than just one record.

Question is short, but I think I explained myself quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the common way is to use a loop which gets one row at a time.